# valores default para namedtuple

Tags: python, python-3.x

Na criação de uma classe posso definir alguns valores padrão:

```
class Point:
    def __init__(self, x, y, z=0):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.z = z
```

Como proceder da mesma forma para namedtuple?

```
from collection import namedtuple
Point = namedtuple('Point', 'x, y, z')
```

Answer (score 1):

Faça uma subclasse no resultado da `namedtuple` e reescreva o valor de `__new__` da seguinte maneira:

```
from collections import namedtuple
class Move(namedtuple('Point', 'x, y, z')):
    def __new__(nome, piece, start, to, captured=None, promotion=None):
        # adicionar valores padrao
        return super(Point, nome).__new__(nome, x, y, z=0)
```

Comment: tem alguma maneira de faze-lo sem declarar uma nova classe?

Comment: No teste observei que a classe Move herda da classe Point, desejo criar a Point com namedtuple, e colocar z como valor default.

Answer (score 1):

No python3 use `.__new__.__defaults__` para atribuir valores default.

```
Points = namedtuple('Points', 'x y z')
Points.__new__.__defaults__ = (None,None,'Foo')
Points()
Points(x=None, y=None, z='Foo')
```

Comment: É isto mesmo que eu quero. Valeu.
Mas tem como definir valor apenas para z?

Comment: Acho que não, mas não serve definir os outros como `None`?